# I'm looking for Docker image containing az cli with "datafactory" az cli extension

Tags: docker

I'm looking for Docker image containing az cli installation along with "datafactory" az cli extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that one exists - but you can build your own.

Here's a snippet from one of my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Based on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/blob/main/containers/azure-cli/.devcontainer/Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:bullseye

# [Option] Install zsh
ARG INSTALL_ZSH="false"
# [Option] Upgrade OS packages to their latest versions
ARG UPGRADE_PACKAGES="false"

# Install needed packages and setup non-root user. Use a separate RUN statement to add your own dependencies.
ARG USERNAME=vscode
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID
COPY library-scripts/*.sh /tmp/library-scripts/
RUN bash /tmp/library-scripts/common-debian.sh "${INSTALL_ZSH}" "${USERNAME}" "${USER_UID}" "${USER_GID}" "${UPGRADE_PACKAGES}" "true" "true" \
    # Install the Azure CLI
    && bash /tmp/library-scripts/azcli-debian.sh \
    # Clean up
    && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/library-scripts

# Install AZ CLI extensions we need, using a global directory
ENV AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR=/opt/azcliextensions
WORKDIR /opt
RUN mkdir azcliextensions \
    && az extension add --name account --upgrade

# Install additional libraries
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends gettext-base
```

The tricksy bit was that AZ CLI extensions normally install per-user, so installation in the Dockerfile would normally have no effect.

Setting the environment variable `AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview?view=azure-cli-latest#install-extensions)) addresses this.